# query the percentage of occurrences in an SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of names, where each row has the columns `name`, and `occurrences`.

I'd like to calculate the percentage of a certain name from the table.

How can I do that in one query?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count the number of rows that contain a specific name?

Comment: So every row has an `occurrences INTEGER` field so actually it's `SUM(occurrences)`. Yes, I'd like to calculate the percentage (could be 0-100) of that name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very elegant due to the subquery in the field list but this will do the job if you want it in one query:

```
SELECT 
  `name`,
  (CAST(SUM(`occurance`) AS DOUBLE)/CAST((SELECT SUM(`occurance`) FROM `user`) AS DOUBLE)) as `percent`
FROM 
  `user`
WHERE
   `name`='miroslav';
```

[Example Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8XVwBCVhKcjtMsi3W5EXwe/0#&togetherjs=9Cc0NOlMs4)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 3):

You can get it by using `SUM(occurrences)`:

```
select 
  name,
  100.0 * sum(occurrences) / (select sum(occurrences) from users) as percentage
from 
  users
where name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: @forpas This does not count the number of occurrences, only the single user in the table, and divides it against the count of users in the table. Assuming there is only 1 row per user (users are unique) this query will have the same value for any user you query :/

Comment: From the comments and the acceptance of the answer you can decide if this is what the OP wanted or not.

Comment: Oh actually I didn't notice that (I unaccepted, sorry)

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: each row has an `occurrences` field, so we need to `SUM(occurrences)` first and then make the percentage calculation

Comment: And you need which percentage?

Comment: Yes, but it could be 0-100 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, cast(sum(occurance) as float) /
(select sum(occurance) from test) * 100 percentage FROM test
where name like '%dog%'
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8XVwBCVhKcjtMsi3W5EXwe/0)

Answer (score 1):

I think conditional aggregation is the best approach:

```
select sum(case when name = @name then occurrences else 0 end) / sum(occurrences) as ratio
from t;
```

If you want an actual percentage between 0 and 100 multiply by 100.